# Router behind Modem (Thomson TWG87OUG and ASUS RT-AC66U)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking, modem

I have a Thomson TWG87OUG. The Thomson Modem has Wifi, LAN, DDNS and Forwarding which I am using currently. But there is some functionality I am missing so I want to buy a Router, the ASUS TR-AC66U, which has the features that I need, like VPN Server, network printer, a Cloud and stuff like that.

So now I need to know how to downgrade the Thomson modem to simply connect the Asus router to the internet?

I have looked into the Manual of the Modem but there was nothing that helped me. And like I am not so familiar with the terms of this topic I am asking here paralel to my research. So I would aprecheate all the help I can get :)

If I can help with some more informations, I will give them to you. Like I said I am not familiar with this topic so I don't know what exactly you or I (lets say we) need to know.

**UPDATE**

I juste learnd that I have to use the bridge mode of my Thomson modem is that right?
In my Webinterface of the Thomson I just find the term bridge in the wireless section.

**Update**

In a forum I read that I also can use DMZ Host (Expose Host) functionality to expose the Router to the WAN and there fore get the public IP. So again is did I got this right? ^^
And, does the router tets his own IP in the LAN (which will differ from the one of my modem - 192.168.0.1)? I think yes but I'm starting to get confused.

**Update**

Ok, i simply did it now. The Router can access to the internet through the modem. Now I would like to know what services I will have to leave running and which ones I can disable. Should I already post this in a new question?

Thanks already!

Comment: you have access to the modem? Sounds to me like you're having A1, the austrian ISP. be craeful with that thing

Comment: I have UPC as ISP

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual at http://www.upc-cablecom.ch/content/dam/www-upc-cablecom-ch/Support/manuals/de/int/original_thomson_twg870_manual.pdf, pages 73-78,you need to ask your cable company for a configuration file that changes the router from RT-mode to CM-mode. Then you can put your new firewall as a "computer" behind the modem.

Comment: There must be a simpler way. I mean, this is basic functionality, or am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is a Routed configuration.

You may find more answers by questioning in this forum: http://www.dieschmids.at/forum/index,
they discuss configurations for Thomson/Speedtouch particular from austrian ISPs there.